# DataFrame.drop works with lists but not tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I do not find it intuitive that when a `tuple` is passed to `DataFrame.drop()`, it throws an error but when a `list` is passed it works.

Given this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4),columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

The following works:

```
df.drop(['A', 'B'], axis=1)
```

but the following doesn't:

```
df.drop(('A', 'B'), axis=1)
```

Error:

```
KeyError: "[('A', 'B')] not found in axis"
```

The error makes it a bit clearer what the code is trying to do but it still doesn't make sense to me. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: As the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) states you can pass it `list like` object. Why would you want to pass it tuples instead? Not much intuition here in my opinion, just how the API was designed.

Comment: I read the docs before I asked. 'list-like' - to me a tuple is list like. I know its immutable but this is exactly a place where you want to use an "immutable list".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tuples` are imutable and hashable objects and therefore, you may have `tuples` as indexes in your data frame. However, they're also iterables, so this is a source of ambiguity: when using tuples, do you mean an iterable or do you mean an object itself? Since they're hashable, pandas interpret as the latter, and tries to find, in your case, a column holding the tuple `('A', 'B')` as its name.

`lists` on the other hand are not hashable because they are mutable, and you can't have them as indexes/column. Hence, there's no ambiguity there: when you pass a list, you always mean an iterable.

Comment: Yeah, I read the docs before I asked - I think they need to use mutable/immutable rather than "list like" - a tuple is list like.

Comment: @s5s Not quite... a list like object is an mutable iterable, a tuple is immutable. That's why multiIndex keys are internally represented by tuples.